# What does a backslash in C++ mean?

Tags: c++, syntax

What does this code: (especially, what does a backslash '\' ? )

```
s23_foo += \ 
s8_foo * s16_bar;
```

I added the datatypes, because they might be relevant.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Backslashes denote two different things in C++, depending on the context.

### As A Line Continuation

Outside of a quotes string (see below), a `\` is used as a line continuation character.  The newline that follows at the end of the line (not visible) is effectively ignored by the preprocessor and the following line is appended to the current line.

So:

```
s23_foo += \ 
s8_foo * s16_bar;
```

Is parsed as:

```
s23_foo += s8_foo * s16_bar;
```

Line continuations can be strung together.  This:

```
s23_foo += \ 
s8_foo * \
s16_bar;
```

Becomes this:

```
s23_foo += s8_foo * s16_bar;
```

In C++ whitespace is irrelevant in most contexts, so in this particular example the line continuation is not needed.  This should compile just fine:

```
s23_foo += 
s8_foo * s16_bar;
```

And in fact can be useful to help paginate the code when you have a long sequence of terms.

Since the preprocessor processed a `#define` until a newline is reached, line continuations are most useful in macro definitions.  For example:

```
#define FOO() \
s23_foo += \ 
s8_foo * s16_bar;
```

Without the line continuation character, `FOO` would be empty here.

### As An Escape Sequence

Within a quotes string, a backslash is used as a delimiter to begin a 2-character escape sequence.  For example:

```
"hello\n"
```

In this string literal, the `\` begins an escape sequence, with the escape code being `n`.  `\n` results in a newline character being embedded in the string.  This of course means if you want a string to include the `\` character, you have to escape that as well:

```
"hello\\there"
```

results in the string as viewed on the screen:

> hello\there

The various escape sequences are documented [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape).

Comment: This is  worth mention: `code;//comment\<new-line>comment continues<new-line>code;`

Answer (score 27):

It lets you continue a statement onto the next line - typically you only need it inside a #define macro block

Comment: So it'd be more accurate to say that outside those macros it doesn't really do anything.

Comment: @millimoose no, you can still write valid code outside macros using backslashes .. but it's REALLY ugly ;)

Comment: @Polentino My point is, if you just *omit* the backslash in the cases you mention, the code works anyway.

Comment: @millimoose you can use a backslash to have a `//` comment span multiple lines. :P

Comment: @millimoose If you combine many backslahes, you can draw a [picture](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8909176/1070480)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it allows you to continue the statement onto the next line, so it can be read as `s23_foo += s8_foo * s16_bar;`.

Answer (score -1):

you can also use some unique code

```
cout<<"\a";
cout<<"\t";
cout<<"\n";
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this \a or \t is other thing than the original context. ` \(backslash)` is just a continuation