# What does the \ symbol do in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm sorry it's such a stupid question, but special characters are so hard to search about on google.

I'm trying to understand this hacky looking code as so:

```
#define DEFUN(funcname, cmdname, cmdstr, helpstr) \
  static int funcname (struct cmd_element *, struct vty *, int, char **); \
  static struct cmd_element cmdname = \
  { \
    cmdstr, \
    funcname, \
    helpstr \
  }; \
  static int funcname \
  (struct cmd_element *self, struct vty *vty, int argc, char **argv)
```

Answer (score 1):

It lets you continue your statement on the next line

See: [What does a backslash in C++ mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19405196/what-does-a-backslash-in-c-mean)

Answer (score 1):

In this context it specifies that the macro definition is continued on the next line. Without it, you'd have to write everything in a single line.