# "// \" Next Line automatically commented out in C++ after putting this?

Tags: c++

Why the next line after //\ is commented out in C++ ? Like I know about "//" and "/* ... */ " but after putting //\ the next line is automatically commented out !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19405196/what-does-a-backslash-in-c-mean probably better duiplicate as more generic answer...

Comment: Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-operator-in-c/8909176#8909176) recently revived on [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402446/is-this-old-answer-to-an-old-question-a-good-example-of-a-good-answer) happens to be applicable here, too ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\` at the end of a line is line continuation for comments and preprocessor.